I'm having trouble accessing the files array in my React component named 'Files' after dispatching an action to add a file to the Redux store
I can not access a files array in a component named 'Files'
Dispatching the Action:
This function handles the change event when a file is selected. It extracts metadata from the file and dispatches an action pushFile with this metadata to add it to the Redux store.
const handleFileChange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0]

        if (file) {
            const fileMetaData = {
                name: file.name,
                size: file.size,
                type: file.type,
                lastModified: file.lastModified
            }

            dispatch(pushFile(fileMetaData))

            // optionally we can upload to server from here ...
        }

}

Redux Store Configuration:
This code configures the Redux store using configureStore from Redux Toolkit. It combines reducers, where fileReducer is responsible for managing file-related state.
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import fileReducer from './fileSlice'

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        fileUpload: fileReducer
    }
})

export default store;

File Reducer:
This file defines a slice of the Redux store state for managing files. The pushFile reducer adds a file to the files array in the state.
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    files: []
}

const fileSlice = createSlice({
    name: "file",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        pushFile: (state, action) => {
            console.log("Action payload: ", action.payload);
            state.files.push(action.payload)
            console.log("Updated State:", [...state.files]);
        }
    }
})

export const { pushFile } = fileSlice.actions
export default fileSlice.reducer

Accessing Files in the Files Component:
This code snippet extracts the files array from the Redux store state using the useSelector hook. It logs changes to the files array using the useEffect hook.
const files = useSelector((state) => state.file?.files || []);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Files changed:", files);
}, [files]);

Here are the outputs when I try to upload a file:
Output
Issue:
Despite dispatching the pushFile action, the files array in the Files component remains empty or unchanged.
Expected Output:
The files array in the Files component should contain the newly added file metadata after dispatching the pushFile action.

Issue
The fileReducer state is stored under a fileUpload key
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    fileUpload: fileReducer
  }
});

So the state you are selecting is incorrect:
const files = useSelector((state) => state.file?.files || []);

Here state.file is undefined.
The name property of createSlice is used to prefix the generated  slice actions, e.g. "file/pushFile" as the action type if you inspected the store via the Redux-Devtools.
Solution Suggestion
Update the selector function to select valid state.
Example:
const files = useSelector((state) => state.fileUpload.files);

or alternatively you could rename the state to match what you are selecting.
Example:
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    file: fileReducer
  }
});

const files = useSelector((state) => state.file.files);


You're him dude.

@HarisSohail Yes, I am me? Was there some additional question or concern? I don't follow your comment.
